# Row background full width inside col-8 bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a classic structure of html code with bootstrap 4. i want to put a background-color in full width of panel in a col-8. here is my code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">

    </div>

    <div class="row my-panel">
     <!-- i want to fill this panel with a full width background color-->
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-4">
     <!-- a sticky top panel which vertically scroll with the page-->
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is my-panel is not on full width because the col-8 is the parent and what i want to do is  to fill my-panel with a color but not only for the width of the col-8 but i want to fill 100% of the screen's width

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Please edit your question to include all of the *relevant code* in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so i edited my post and added the problem and what i want to do however i had put this 4 div because i think it will be useful for who those who want to help

Comment: Thanks for editing, what you want to so is clearer now, but I you haven't included the CSS you were using to try to do this? Also, I'm not sure what you want to do is possible... if I understand correctly, your coloured panel would cut through just a part of the sticky top panel and I don't know how that could be done with the structure you have. If you could show us a working example so we can see what it looks like, it might help us come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your question is not clear, but since you say you edited it I tried my best to understand the question.

Bootstrap works in a grid system. So if you set a class as col-4 it'll set up a small box (column) inside this grid to let you throw in your elements in. The rest of this row will remain empty. Furthermore, due to HTML divs works in a parent/child sense, if you add a `col-8` inside a `container` and tried adding `width:100%;` (CSS) in the `col-8` and expected to see a stretched `container`, it simply won't work.

So, you have to edit that `container`'s css attributes. But I would suggest you make another parent div before the container and add css into it.

I think what you want to do something similar to the below image.

I've added background colours to the divs, so you might be able to understand what I've done here. Also, I believe that this way your question of adding background colours, might be answered.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <div style="background-color: green;">
        <div style="background-color: blue;">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-8" style="background-color: red; width: 100%;">
                    <div class="row" >
                
                    </div>

                    <div class="row my-panel">
                    <!-- i want to fill this panel with a full width background color -->
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maiores iusto consectetur,
                        aliquid laborum dicta nobis magni atque voluptatem ullam, natus deserunt, animi corrupti sunt nesciunt fugiat asperiores nam delectus quam.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-4" style="background-color: yellow;">
            <!--  a sticky top panel which vertically scroll with the page -->
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Maiores iusto consectetur,
            aliquid laborum dicta nobis magni atque voluptatem ullam, natus deserunt, animi corrupti sunt nesciunt fugiat asperiores nam delectus quam.
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```